# Custom Directive to change number format in input and use the number in calculation in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have this input controller :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="someValue" fromControlName="someControl"/>
```

To show numbers in this input, I have a custom requirement, for thousands separator, I should use " "(space) and not ",".

you can find the demo here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6umyrw

There are two issues : first, I think setting the initiate value  through ngOnInit is not correct.

Second and most importantly, in **AppComponent** when calculation happens, it reads the number with " "(space) as its separator so at the end it results to NaN. Therefore I want to add something to Directive, the "val.frmCtrl" is read as number.

Comment: And, where are you blocked ? Why can't you format the variable before assigning it the control ? Also, you are mixing reactive forms (`fromControlName`) with template driven forms (`[(ngModel)]`), which is probably a bad idea and could explain your problem.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I am not a senior Angular developer. I know that before accessing the from control value, now I Number() to format a number like "465 000.2" (note that numbers are separated by space) but it does not work and shows NaN. All I have used is in the provided sample . I am looking for a way to read ctrl Value without having to format it every where I am using it.

Comment: If the value is a string, then you will have some conversion anyway. But as I hope that the format will always be the same through the application, you will just create a static method and call it everywhere you need. Here, the formatting will just remove all the whitespace characters. You can do it with `numberAsString.replace(/\s/g, '');`